# irobot create 3 ros2 humble

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to run the Irobot Create 3 with Ros 2 Humble or is it fixed to Galactic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409525/irobot-create-3-ros2-humble/) by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1999 on 2022-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I found [here](https://qiita.com/tomoyafujita/items/8d93229d6e0fb9dc6694)

Cross communication is possible from Galactic to Humble so I will start by try it out

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2022-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

FYI: there's a beta release for Create 3 with ROS 2 Humble: https://iroboteducation.github.io/create3_docs/releases/h_0_0/

However, as you said, most features work across Galactic-Humble.

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2022-11-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1